# Any other process faster than sqldf in r

Tags: r, dplyr, data-manipulation, sqldf

I have 2 dataframes

df1 has 700,000 datapoints

- ID1: Categorical Variable has 400+ categories
- Date1: 1 year data
- MST1: 2 level variable 1/2
- Confirmation Number: unique Identifier

sample data:

```
ID1 ExtractDate1    MktSeg1 ConfirmationNo
145  3/7/2017          2    29083253
145  3/7/2017          1    29085100
145  3/7/2017          1    29085102
145  3/7/2017          1    29085106
145  3/7/2017          1    29084895
145  3/7/2017          1    29084953
```

df2 has 100,000 datapoints

- ID2: Categorical Variable has 400+ categories
- Date2: 1 year data
- MST2: 2 level variable 1/2
- Conf No: unique Identifier

I want to make a new variable, flag to df1 which is marked as 1 when confirmation number present in df1 and df2 else 0

I've achieved this by using the following:

```
combi1 <- sqldf("SELECT Distinct ID1,
            ExtractDate1,
            MktSeg1,
            ConfirmationNo,
            CASE
            WHEN confno IS NOT NULL
            THEN 1
            ELSE 0
            END AS 'Flag'
            FROM df1 
            LEFT JOIN df2  ON ID1 = ID2
            AND ExtractDate2 >= ExtractDate1
            AND ConfirmationNo = confno", drv = "SQLite")
```

It take more than 20-30 minutes to give the results, is there any better way of doing it?

I've tried this

```
combi3 <- left_join(tbl_df(df1),tbl_df(df2),
                by = c("ID1" = "ID2" , "ExtractDate1" <= "ExtractDate2", "ConfirmationNo" = "ConfNo")) %>%
      select(distinct(ID1, ExtractDate1, MktSeg1, ConfirmationNo))
```

it is throwing the following error:

```
`by` can't contain join column `TRUE` which is missing from LHS
```

Comment: Convert to data.table `setDT`, then set the keys for ID columns `setkey`, then use `%in%` as suggested in MHammer's post below.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using the data you provided and one similar to it for a second data frame, you can use the `%in%` operator:

```
df1 <- read.table(text = "ID1 ExtractDate1    MktSeg1 ConfirmationNo
145  3/7/2017          2    29083253
                  145  3/7/2017          1    29085100
                  145  3/7/2017          1    29085102
                  145  3/7/2017          1    29085106
                  145  3/7/2017          1    29084895
                  145  3/7/2017          1    29084953", header = TRUE)

df2 <- read.table(text = "ID1 ExtractDate1    MktSeg1 ConfirmationNo
145  3/7/2017          2    29083253
                  145  3/7/2017          1    29085106
                  145  3/7/2017          1    29084895
                  145  3/7/2017          1    29084953
                  145  3/7/2017          1    29084899
                  145  3/7/2017          1    29084959", header = TRUE)

df1$conf_flag <- as.numeric(df1$ConfirmationNo %in% df2$ConfirmationNo)
df1
```

Comment: This worked for me, it is pretty fast as well. Thank you so much.

Answer (score 3):

If you want to stick with `sqldf`, which may not be the fastest option, then you may try rewriting your query to use `EXISTS`:

```
combi1 <- sqldf("SELECT ID1,
            ExtractDate1,
            MktSeg1,
            ConfirmationNo,
            CASE WHERE EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM df2
                WHERE ID1 = ID2
                AND ExtractDate2 >= ExtractDate1
                AND ConfirmationNo = confno)
            THEN 1
            ELSE 0
            END AS Flag
            FROM df1", drv = "SQLite")
```

Switching to `EXISTS` means we don't have to use `DISTINCT` anymore.  It also lets us do away with the left join, because the logic can stop scanning after the first match.

Note that there is a lot more tuning we could do on an actual database.  For `sqldf` this may be as much as we can do.

Comment: I tried this as well but it is still taking more time. It does the task as well. Thank you so much.